# What is the generic key binding that matches if no other binding does in zsh?

Tags: zsh

In [fish shell](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/cmds/bind.html), The generic key binding that matches if no other binding does can be set by specifying a SEQUENCE of the empty string (that is, '' ).

For example:

```
bind '' self-insert
```

I checked the [documentation of zsh](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#Zle-Builtins) for similar functionality, it says:

> -m
>
> Add the built-in set of meta-key bindings to the selected keymap. Only keys that are unbound or bound to self-insert are affected.

I am not sure whether i can use it for my purpose.

What is the generic key binding that matches if no other binding does in zsh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `zsh`, the widget that is invoked when no mapping is found for a key (byte sequence sent by the terminal) is the `undefined-key` widget which by default beeps, but you could redefine it to something else such as:

```
undefined-key() {
  zle -M "${(q+)KEYS} is not bound to anything"
  zle .$WIDGET
}
zle -N undefined-key
```

Or make it insert those bytes raw left of the cursor with:

```
undefined-key() LBUFFER+=$KEYS
zle -N undefined-key
```

It is not `self-insert`, `self-insert` in keymaps such as `emacs` or `viins` is bound to keys by virtue of it being bound to `R`anges of bytes:

```
$ bindkey | awk '$NF == "self-insert"'
" "-"~" self-insert
"\M-^@"-"\M-^?" self-insert
```

That's all byte values for 32 (space) to 255 (M-^?) here excluding 127 (`^?` which is bound to `backward-delete-char`).

You can bind to something else with:

```
my-self-insert() { zle -M "You entered <$KEYS>"; zle self-insert; }
zle -N my-self-insert
for range (' -~' '\x80-\xff') bindkey -R $range my-self-insert
```

Though a maybe more idiomatic way is to redefine `self-insert`:

```
self-insert() { zle -M "You entered <$KEYS>"; zle .$WIDGET; }
```

Beware that for multibyte characters, the widget is invoked once for each byte in the character and AFAIK, bounds of the range can only be single bytes.

`self-insert` also only works for single bytes, though you could always do:

```
my-self-insert() {
  zle -M "You entered <$KEYS>"
  repeat ${NUMERIC-1} LBUFFER+=$KEYS
}
for c ({$'\ua0'..$'\uff'}) bindkey $c my-self-insert
```

To bind `my-self-insert` to Unicode character U+00A1 to U+00FF and do the self-inserting by hand by appending `$KEYS` (the bytes or sequence of bytes sent by the terminal that led to invoking the widget) to `$LBUFFER` (the section of the line editing buffer left of the cursor).

Comment: shift+del print 2~, alt+del print 3~, ctrl+del print 5~ in the terminal when I use all the three functions. I am not understanding the reason.

Comment: @AhmadIsmail, that's not really related. My terminal emulator sends `ESC[3;2~` upon pressing Shift+Del. There's no mapping for that sequence. There's a mapping for `\e[3~` (the sequence sent upon Del) which is the closest, after reading `\e[3` zle waits for the extra characters that may complete the sequence but that `;` doesn't satisfy so you get beep and so that's discarded. Next come `2~` which are bound to self-insert.

Comment: This information was very helpful.

Comment: @AhmadIsmail, see edit for the mention of the `undefined-key` widget which I realise might have been what you were looking for (and is responsible for the *beep* I mention in my earlier comment).